# Ajax only submits once

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a large table that has addresses and other demo info on each row. I have added a form and submit button to each row to save updated data. When it is submitted, data in a  gets populated with HTML and the form contents sent via ajax.
The problem is, it only works once. If the form is submitted it sends the data and populates the  as expected, but the form isn't sent a second time. I have a skeletal template below. I've tried using the live() function in various ways I've seen on here, but I can't get it to work.

Edit: how can i make the result div #G1 fade out after a few seconds? Couldn't get that working either.

Relevant JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Frm1").submit(function (event) {
        var values = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "savedata.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#G1").replaceWith(msg).fadeIn(2000);
                $('#ty').html('<select name="thanks"><option value="1">Yes</option><option value="0" selected>No</option></select>');
            },

        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="maint">
<tr>
    <td><strong><a href="mailto:" title="<p>Address:<br>1417 Apt 38<br>NY<p>Phone:4253455550</p>" id="1_pop">Bpbb BB</a></strong>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Cara JT</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <form id="Frm1">
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="rsvp">
            <input type="text" id="gift" name="gift" value="3">
    </td>
    <td id="ty"></td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save Row" />
        <div id="G1"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: `.live()` is long since deprecated and removed from the latest versions. Look up [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: You are replacing the `#G1` element altogether. You probably want to use `.text` or `.html` instead if `.replaceWith`.

Comment: Thanks Juhana. That works great, along with adding preventDefault. I'm still having difficulty getting the div to fade out. I added the .html, but I get an error saying milliseconds is not defined, referring to the fadeout(). I tried specifying with fadeout(1600, "slow") but no go.

Comment: @user2558042 `.html` doesn't return the jQuery collection. Try putting `$("#G1").fadeIn(2000);` on a separate line.

Comment: I tried the new line. However, console is still showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: miliseconds is not defined". I've tried: $("#G1").fadeOut(2000); and also $("#G1").fadeOut(fast);

Comment: @user2558042 Sounds like you have other issues. You should try to get a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) up and running that reproduces this error.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing `return false` for `event.preventDefault();`

**EDIT**
For the people that think that this is a bad answer, please read: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Your point is valid and a good practice, but it doesn't answer the actual question. I guess that is why you've been downvoted.

Comment: His problem is that his AJAX submits only once, whereas your answer would prevent it from submitting.  You're right about what you say, but you're not addressing the question directly... This would make a good comment, but it's not an answer to this specific question.

Comment: mmm, Maybe I'm wrong but, when an event handled by jQuery returns false, this event handler is removed, right? If I'm correct, then the form will only be submited once.

Comment: You're wrong. `return false` does not make the event handler disappear.